# Inline-block elements and vertical-align reasoning

Tags: html, vertical-alignment, css

I have 2 div boxes next to each other using display: inline-block.

Without content both inline-block divs are vertically aligned to top.

If both have content they also vertically align to top.

If only one of them has text content then the div box that has text content is vertically aligned to bottom while the one wihtout any text content remains vertically aligned to top.

If one box has plain text content and the other has e.g. an input field or a header tag then the box with only text content moves down only slighly (maybe 2 or 3px) while the one with the input or header tag stays on top.

Please see jsfiddle link below

Why did the creators do this instead of always aligning them to top? Is there a deeper reason behind this?

Comment: Can you post a demo of what you are doing?

Comment: I am testing and asking myself why: http://jsfiddle.net/genwQ/

Comment: Did you try `float: left;`?

Comment: yes float would work. As well would vertical-align: top. I am interested weather there is a reasoning why vertical-align: top is not default. I want to better understand element positioning...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/genwQ/3, http://jsfiddle.net/X3RLB/2 hope something can help

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

In your example just add:

```
.content_boxes{
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: lightgreen;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/genwQ/1/

You have to set `vertical-align:top;` to each element is `display:inline-block;`. Careful not to confuse: it is the element, NOT the parent.

Example:

```
ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/X3RLB/

Realize that an unwanted space appears between your `inline-block` elements. This space CANNOT be removed with the `margin:0px;` property. To remove them you must add a comment tag between `inline-block` the elements.

Example:

```
<div id="content_cnt">
    <div class="content_boxes"></div><!--
    --><div class="content_boxes">dsasda</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/genwQ/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I know how to remedy my issue. I am looking for the WHY...to better understand element positioning